# Passing a valule to JSF Managed bean from h:dataTable results in the same value passed over

Tags: java, jsf-2, hyperlink, facelets

I went through similar questions asked here, but it did not solve the my problem.

I have an object `UserDetails` whose attributes I display in `h:dataTable`;I also have a `h:commandLink` in each row that is used to deactivate user. When I click on 'Deactivate' link, I pass the `userId` in the `UserDetails` to the controller.

```
 class UserDetails
 {
  int userId;
  String userName;
 }
```

My ManagedBean has the following code

```
    public String deactivateUser(int userId)
     {
            //Use the user id and do deactivate operation
            return "userpage";
      }
```

Here `UserDetails` is an array declared in controller.

And this is the code in JSF page :

```
      <h:dataTable width="100%" value="#{myController.userDetails}" 
           var="userDetails">
               <h:column> <f:facet name="header"> userId </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{userDetails.userId}" />
               </h:column>
                 <h:column> <f:facet name="header"> userName </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{userDetails.userName}" />
               </h:column>
                 <h:column> <f:facet name="header"> Deactivate User </f:facet>
                <h:commandLink value="#{msg['link.edit']}"  action="#{myController.deactivateuser(userDetails.userId)}" /> |
               </h:column>
       </h:dataTable>
```

**The Problem :**

Imagine The following data is present in datatable

```
userId      Name    

 50        Taylor       Deactivate
 55        Anna         Deactivate
 59        Rock         Deactivate
 64        Hudson       Deactivate
 71        Batman       Deactivate
```

Now if I click on Deactivate link for 'Anna' , userId 71 is passed instead of 55. In short, the user Id at the end is passed whichever link is clicked.

Why is this happening ?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: That makes no sense.. Which JSF implementation version are you using? Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with the full testable example?

Comment: Mojarra JSF 2.2 is the JSF implementation we use.

Comment: Which EL are you using? Have you tried giving the whole `UserDetails`-Object as parameter (it's a object, the other is a primitive data type)? and yes, a SSCCE would be a great idea! ;-)

Comment: I tried passing the whole object. Same result.

Comment: Assuming you return a `List<UserDetails>` in `myController.userDetails` , the example should be fine and I don't see any problems in that. still, Code of your Managed bean could find other possible reasons.